# How to get real request client's ip from App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express

I have set `app.set('trust_proxy', 1);` just like [this page](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/resources/runtime#extending_the_runtime) suggests 
but for each request it gives the following ip address 169.254.160.2 ...

```
req.ip => 169.254.160.2
req.ips => [ '169.254.160.2' ]
```

Headers suggested headers are also with the same value ...
So how do I get the ip because all "what is my ip" sites tells me that my ip is 130.204.67.112

So how do i get my real ip in App Engine ?

ps. I'm using custom docker container for my app if that matters (I think it dosen't but still) I have migrated from heroku where it needs `app.enable('trust_proxy')` and it did work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `x-appengine-user-ip` header directly:

```
var ip = req.headers['x-appengine-user-ip'];
```

Note: Some people get `undefined` with the `x-appengine-user-ip`: you can test with `x-forwarded-for` instead. (TY Jay)

Comment: yes i did figure out that this is the only header that returns correct ip address (just didn't have time to make a self answer ...)

Comment: I'm using Adonis.js as a backend node.js framework on Google App Engine. `x-appengine-user-ip` gave me `undefined`.

`x-forwarded-for` has been the right header to retrieve the client IP in my case.

Comment: x-forwarded-for is useful if you use cdn to boost app engine pages.

Comment: Google docs for the runtime suggest `X-Forwarded-For`. I'm curious if there are docs stating that `x-appengine-user-ip` is an official header? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/request-headers